# Can I tell if a user opened my app by tapping on a toast notification?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there anyway to get the context that an app has been opened? ie. Has the user pressed on a received toast notification or have they clicked on the application tile? My reasoning is that I will send the user a toast notification (eg. 1 new message for you!). If they tap on the toast notification I would like the app to open at an inbox like screen as opposed to my home screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some parameter to `Toast` or `Tile` `Url`. For example, `/Views/MainPage.xaml?from=toast` that tells you that user tap a toast instead of just launch your app from a menu. It's called `Deep Links`

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else who comes across this and to be clear, add a parameter to the toast message such as: `<wp:Param>/SettingsPage.xaml?from=toast</wp:Param>` and get the query string in the `OnNavigatedTo` event.