# Can I send parameters in push notifications to toast (Windows Phone)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast, mpns

I have a case in my app where I need to send a push notification to a user device when the application is offline and appears as a toast notification.

I need when the user clicks on the toast message to navigate to a specific page in my application depending on the message. I know that this is available in toast notifications but can I send parameters from my server to the toast to determine the page?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153113/can-i-tell-if-a-user-opened-my-app-by-tapping-on-a-toast-notification)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course you can.

The XML of the toast notification you send from your server looks like this:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
     <wp:Toast>
         <wp:Text1>[string]</wp:Text1>
         <wp:Text2>[string]</wp:Text2>
         <wp:Param>[string]</wp:Param>
     </wp:Toast>
   </wp:Notification>;
```

You use the `Param` parameter to send parameters to your app :

> You can use the Param element to deep link to a specific
>   screen in your app. Here are the allowed formats. Any string used for
>   the following examples must be 256 characters or less.
>
> - /page1.xaml – Defines the screen to navigate to in the app when the app starts. The string must begin with a "/".
> - /page1.xaml?value1=1234 &value2=9876 – Defines the screen to navigate to when the app starts, along with name/value pairs of info.
>     The string must begin with a "/".
> - ?value1=1234 &value2=9876 – Contains name/value pairs of info passed to the default start screen of the app. The string must begin
>     with a "?".

(taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))

Comment: Hi Eran, just a question, I need the value in <wp:Text1> in the page I'm navigating from <wp:Param>
Do I need to add this value into <wp:Param> as well? Or do I have some way to get it from OnNavigatedTo method in the desired page? Many thanks

Comment: @NadavN7 From the docs, it doesn't look like you have access to the `Text1` value of the notification in `OnNavigatedTo`, so you might have to add it to the `Param`.

Comment: Yes this is valid for all WP versions AFAIK.

Comment: It looks like if you have a WP app compatible WP 8.0 / 8.1 / 10.0, on some end devices under WP 10, the <wp:Param>[string]</wp:Param> is not taken into account anymore. The onNavigatedTo() method doesn't show it (in your NavigationEventArgs, the URI has no parameters)... Any reason why?