# Deep toast notification in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Is there any way to receive parameters from deep toast notification, so that I can navigate to specified game state? I see deep toast allow this but its parameters passed to

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
```

and I can't figure out how to handle it, because it is unavaible in XNA.
If I send deep toast notification while app is running I recieve all parameters and can handle them. So my question is similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208553/can-i-send-parameters-in-push-notifications-to-toast-windows-phone) but I need to do that in XNA.
PS: xna/wp7 project, not slxna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information from `NavigationEventArgs` in XNA is passed in [LaunchParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.launchparameters.aspx), which is avaible from main game class.